# Spritekit Coordinate System unexpected positioning

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, coordinate

I have the classes AttackArea, Player and GameScene.
I want to instantiate a new AttackArea object and place it near the Player, depending on the Players facing. Now I have problems with the right positioning. If I add the AttackArea as a child of GameScene, the positioning works as expected. But If I do that, the AttackArea isn't moving with the Player. Otherwise if I add the AttackArea as a child of the Player, it's moving with the Player. That's exactly what I want. The problem here is that the positioning of the AttackArea is now far away from the Player. This is the code in the Player class:

```
func attack(){
    let attack = AttackArea(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height / 2))
    var animation = ""
    switch playerFacing{
    case .back:
        attack.position = CGPoint(x: self.position.x, y: self.position.y + 40)
        animation = Constants.Actions.playerAttackBack
    case .front:
        attack.position = CGPoint(x: self.position.x, y: self.position.y - 40)
        animation = Constants.Actions.playerAttackFront
    case .left:
        attack.position = CGPoint(x: self.position.x - 40, y: self.position.y)
        animation = Constants.Actions.playerAttackLeft
    case .right:
        attack.position = CGPoint(x: self.position.x + 40, y: self.position.y)
        animation = Constants.Actions.playerAttackRight
    case .none:
        break
    }
    attack.zPosition = self.zPosition + 1
    attack.setup()
    if animation != ""{
        self.run(SKAction(named: animation)!)
    }
    self.addChild(attack)
}
```

The first picture shows the situation when the AttackArea is a child of GameScene. The positioning is fine but I want it to be a child of Player.

[image]

The second picture shows the positioning when the AttackArea is a child of Player. The red square in the top right corner is the AttackArea and the red circle is the Player.

[image]

Why is the AttackArea so far away from the Player in this case? How can I archieve the same result as in the first picture with the only exception, that the AttackArea is child of the Player?

Comment: what happens if you take the physicsBody off of the attack area. does it still appear so far away from the player?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't changed anything. The AttackArea is still appearing far away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what happens if you change the positioning to

```
switch playerFacing{
    case .back:
        attack.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0 + 40)
        animation = Constants.Actions.playerAttackBack
    case .front:
        attack.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0 - 40)
        animation = Constants.Actions.playerAttackFront
    case .left:
        attack.position = CGPoint(x: 0 - 40, y: 0)
        animation = Constants.Actions.playerAttackLeft
    case .right:
        attack.position = CGPoint(x: 0 + 40, y: 0)
        animation = Constants.Actions.playerAttackRight
    case .none:
        break
    }
```

I suspect that your player (for example) might be at pos 500, 500 and you are re-adding those values to the attack position so now it's position is 1000, 1040

Comment: glad it worked out for you, you have a good looking game there